# Is there a way to create a sidebar of bullets

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, sidebar

On each individual post im trying to create a sidebar for my sources of information. is it possible to have a sidebar labeled sources with bullet points coming from it that im able to put links?

Comment: Yes - very possible.  Welcome to WPSE.  You will have a few areas to tackle: the HTML markup (recommend using the blog sidebar for this) and the data to display (custom field for `sources` for each post).  When you get stuck on something, come back and ask a well-scoped question that shows what work and research you've already done.   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Welcome to the forum!  Are you comfortable coding, or are you looking for plugins to do all the work for you?  Alternately, I can also think of at least one combination solution which would require some minor coding, and use a plugin to generate the really complex stuff.  Just need to know your experience and comfort level before I suggest something with too many moving parts, or too much coding, etc ...